# Wrong Build.VERSION.SdkInt?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

My app crashes on android 4 (at least) and works on android 8 to 10.
On android 4 (4.4) the error is `Could not find method android.app.Activity.checkSelfPermission` however my code is :

```
       if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt>=BuildVersionCodes.M)
       {
          if (ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this,Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage) != (int)Permission.Granted)
                    RequestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage}, 1);

        }
```

Android 4.4 is less than Android M, no ?
Then, can Build.VERSION.SdkInt return a bad value ?

Comment: Are you 100% sure it is not happening somewhere else?

Comment: Good question, I did a search for that string on the entire solution but didn't find answer, I don't know why but finaly I found one I missed and that didn't have the Build condition. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

On Android 4.4 , it is API 19, checkSelfPermission() didn't get introduced into the native Context until API 23 (Android 6.0). So you will need to use at least version 23.0.0 of the support library.

From the [official android developer site](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting):

If the device is running Android 5.1 or lower, or your app's target SDK is 22 (Android 5.1) or lower: If you list a dangerous permission in your manifest, the user has to grant the permission when they install the app; if they do not grant the permission, the system does not install the app at all.

If the device is running Android 6.0 or higher, and your app's target SDK is 23 (Android 6.0) or higher: The app has to list the permissions in the manifest, and it must request each dangerous permission it needs while the app is running. The user can grant or deny each permission, and the app can continue to run with limited capabilities even if the user denies a permission request.

Comment: Thank you for the answer bu tin fact the good anwser is "no", Build.VERSION.SdkInt returns the good value, I haven't put the condition everywhere. Maybe you can add the fact that BuildVersionCodes.M returns 23 and that so, my code shouldn't crash and the problem must be somewhere else. Then I'll can accept you anwser.

Comment: @Entretoize,Can you provide one sample that can reproduce this issue at github? I will help you to test it at my side, or if you have solution, please share your solution here, thanks.